# Django 1.8 sending mail using gmail SMTP

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I was trying send a mail using `smtp.gmail.com` in django 1.8

My `settings.py` contains:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'  
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'  
EMAIL_PORT=465  
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sarath4coding'  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'  
DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM = 'sarath4coding@gmail.com'
```

```
from django.core import mail
mail.send_mail('subject','message','sarath4coding@gmail.com',['sarath4coding@gmail.com'])
```

But got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/manager/dj1.8/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/manager/dj1.8/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/manager/dj1.8/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/manager/dj1.8/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_smtp_ssl.py", line 14, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuze\n5.7.14 2FDKQt2Dlo2vqFIvbr6DnBItwWvh9DChPwbeTZO66N91gzmiA437Vqs80cZ9-8u13vxq5a\n5.7.14 bVahzO_BQcZ53yKbJ-YbAlmFE1XIK7MfH97O0wI1lvzpTG_WAHuTIBF0HD1GA2icUoUemt\n5.7.14 ErZn4qb942aAIMG103FnrzLp4txXTbXC-wGLpaz5yvnUN5thahvv3-RiIVW8F1QddZKZlg\n5.7.14 qQKpqWw56zr1AcO2s_oaBEt556fQ> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 kx14sm6579665pab.0 - gsmtp')
```

I tried everything the document says and followed many suggested solutions.

like https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, enabling low security apps etc.

but I still got errors

Can anybody tell how to properly configure Django 1.8 to send mail using Gmail.

Comment: I had a similar configuration but with: `EMAIL_HOST_USER='sarath4coding@gmail.com'` and `EMAIL_PORT=587` and `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`

Comment: Same here. Tried every answer below but it is still not working for me.

Answer (score 47):

for me in **settings.py**:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

and **views.py**:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[email])
email.send()
```

and: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and also make sure you turn on permission for less secure apps.

Answer (score 22):

Remember to:

Go to your Google Account settings, find Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps, enable this option.

About this option: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: possibly a more secure option is to add an app specific password: https://security.google.com/settings/u/1/security/apppasswords

Comment: Link is broken @ptim :(

Comment: tx @Vini.g.fer! This help page explains the process: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 12):

I tested this and worked perfect in **django 1.8:**
first you should check [this link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257), provided by google which you did :)
notice that for some strange reasons that I don't know,you have to code like this in `view.py or shell`:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
         ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

also this is my settings in `setting.py` file:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxx' #my gmail password
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com' #my gmail username
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Answer (score 9):

replace in your settings.py file :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
```

by

**`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`**

Answer (score 8):

In settings.py
change this

```
EMAIL_HOST='imap.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'yadavabhishek260@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ='**********'
EMAIL_USE_SSL=False
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Unlock Captcha: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

views.py

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'subject_message',
    'content_message',
    'sender smtp gmail' +'<sender@gmail.com>',
    ['receiver@gmail.com'],
    headers = {'Reply-To': 'contact_email@gmail.com' }
)
email.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this for django 1.11

In settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'sender' #sender mail password
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender@mail.com' #sender mail username
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

In view.py

```
send_mail('mail subject', 'body content',settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                      ['receiver@mail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

and goto https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/security?hl=en to enable Less secure app access