# Error sending email in django through gmail

Tags: python, django, email, gmail, starttls

I am trying to send a mail using django through gmail.

Following is my settings.py code:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@mycompany.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

view.py I am using method send_mail():

```
send_mail(subject, contact_message, emailfrom, emailto)
```

When I execute the code & enter details in my contact form & hit submit.
I get the below error:

```
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Please suggest!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.8 sending mail using gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324005/django-1-8-sending-mail-using-gmail-smtp)

Comment: In the above thread issue was regarding SMTPAuthenticationError & I have SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server. Both are different.

Comment: The solution maybe the same if you read the first answer. Yea SO should provide a flag like "answer already exists".

Comment: I followed same steps as described in the solution but I continue to get the STARTTTLS extenion not supported error. Note: I am using Django 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Gmail, and I don't know Django, but I hope the following explanations will help you.

A quick analysis shows that your situation is kind of odd. There is a simple method to test what capabilities / extension an SMTP server provides: Get a command line `telnet` client, connect to the server in question and query its capabilities. The following shows how this is done in Linux, but it's basically the same with Windows:

```
root@spock:~# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587              <-- Type this on the command line
Trying 74.125.71.109...                              <-- This is output
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.            <-- This is output
Escape character is '^]'.                            <-- This is output
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s196sm2489285wmb.6 - gsmtp  <-- This is output
EHLO localhost.com                                   <-- **YOU** must type this
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [46.83.27.246]   <-- The following lines are output
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS                                         <-- NOTE THIS LINE
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

The key points here are the second command line parameter to the `telnet` command which designates which port to use, and the EHLO command you type (make sure you really type `EHLO` and not `HELO` which is another command).

As you can see from the example, `smtp.gmail.com` definitely supports the STARTTLS command / extension. I have tested this in a normal environment; my Linux box is behind a NAT router which is the usual setup for private households and small companies. No port forwarding or other special configuration is in place.

So the first thing I would recommend is that you repeat this simple test at your place. Then,

- If you get the same result as me, especially if the output you get also contains the line `250-STARTTLS`, there is absolutely no explanation what happens here besides errors in Django itself. Are you using the most recent version? I can't help you here, because I never have used it and I don't know anything about it.
- If the line `250-STARTTLS` is *not* in the output you get, something completely weird must go on. As my example shows, `STARTTLS` *is* supported at least for clients at my place, and there is no reason why it shouldn't be supported for clients at your place.
- Exceptions might be China or similar countries where governments try to prevent the usage of encryption. So I could imagine that Google turns off the STARTTLS extension based on geo-blocking when a client from such a country connects. But I really don't know! People who do are encouraged to leave a comment ...
- Perhaps you are using a proxy which disturbs the communication between your client (Django) and the SMTP server.

I you still haven't found the problem, you could do the following:

- You could try port `25` instead of port `587`. I have verified that `smtp.gmail.com` supports `STARTTLS` on port `25` as well. With most email clients, it doesn't matter if you use port `25` or port `587`. You should be able to make Django use port `25` by saying `EMAIL_PORT = 25` in your configuration file.
- You could try to use implicit `TLS` (most often called `SSL`) instead of the explicit `STARTTLS`. The port which is usually used for this is `465`. To implement this, say `EMAIL_PORT = 465`, `EMAIL_USE_TLS = False` and `EMAIL_USE_SSL = True` in your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks Binarus. Your suggestion to use 
EMAIL_PORT = 465, 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False and 
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True has worked.