# django sending mail [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, django, email

i'm using django-registration in my project to sending email when user forgot password. But i got the error [Errno -2] Name or service not known. Below are my settings and traceback..

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

gaierror at /accounts/password_reset/
    [Errno -2] Name or service not known
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/password_reset/
    Django Version: 1.10.5
    Exception Type: gaierror
    Exception Value:    
    [Errno -2] Name or service not known
    Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection, line 553
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Python Path:    
    ['/vagrant/ifoswork/ifoswork',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
    Server time:    Thu, 5 Oct 2017 14:38:34 +0800
```

Comment: did u set DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

Comment: @amrit i already put those line before this.. but it does not change anything.

Comment: It would not. The issue here is for some reason it cannot resolve the address of the remote server. Are you sure its dns is properly configured (and it's not blocked out by some firewall)?

Answer (score 2):

When I got this error it was caused by the wrong information in the following fields:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Except I am not using gmail, however I did find the following information on [Django 1.8 sending mail using gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324005/django-1-8-sending-mail-using-gmail-smtp#31333304)

> Go to your Google Account settings, find Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps, enable this option.

Essentially the error "[Errno -2] Name or service not known" can not connect to the email server.