# Handling contact form in Django, email not sent

Tags: python, django, sendmail

I have an application whereby a user can contact me by filling out a form and in the form the user just has to fill in his details and his email and subject.

The code throws no error but I could *not receive the mail after setting up everything*, but the contact details gets stored in the database as I want it to be stored.

Below is my code.

**Models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
    sender = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cc_myself = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Message for {}'.format(self.sender)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'sender', 'phone', 'message', 'cc_myself']
```

**Views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if contact_form.is_valid():
            name = contact_form.cleaned_data['name']
            message = contact_form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = contact_form.cleaned_data['sender']
            phone = contact_form.cleaned_data['phone']
            cc_myself = contact_form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

            recipients = ['xxxx@gmail.com']
            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(sender)

            send_mail(name, message, sender, recipients)
            contact_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Message sent successfully')
            return redirect('contact:contact')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error sending your Message')

    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

    context = {
        "contact_form": contact_form,
    }
    template = 'contact.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**gmail server**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**terminal output**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: adie Ugbe
From: abcd@gmail.com
To: xxxx@gmail.com
Date: Sun, 07 Jan 2018 11:11:10 -0000
Message-ID: <20180107111110.29855.10393@1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa>

oh oh no ooo dddddddd se skan
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Successful
```

Comment: Test with fail_silently=False, on your send_mail function, send_mail(name, message, sender, recipients, fail_silently=False) , will raise an smtplib.SMTPException. Maybe is an exception from smtp server.

Comment: Have you checked "spam" folder in your mail box?

Comment: Yes. It’s not there. Not even in sent mail of the sending email

Comment: Did you allow the access to your Google account via https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha ?

Comment: @King Did you try it with a simple backend like the [console backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#console-backend)? Knowing whether another backend works as expected would help narrow where the issue is.

Comment: Please, search other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324005/django-1-8-sending-mail-using-gmail-smtp

Be sure that in settings: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

Comment: You could try to see if the porblem is with smtp / gmail or with your way to handle it, by setting EMAIL_BACKEND to `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`, and checking the console

Comment: @Info-Screen, I know. He wrote: " it shows in terminal that the message is being sent"...Maybe he is seeing it because of the console setting as EMAIL_BACKEND...

Comment: It prints message sent when I inserted a print statement

Comment: I have updated my question to include the terminal output

Comment: found the problem. I realized that I had `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` in my settings file. removing it fixed the problem. it was conflicting the smtp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.8 sending mail using gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324005/django-1-8-sending-mail-using-gmail-smtp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I am configured it. It sends me email successfully. I have done the code please see it. Visit the link for code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ouq5mklq5t51su/mail.zip?dl=0

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'user',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from user.models import *
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from user.forms import *

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if contact_form.is_valid():
            name = contact_form.cleaned_data['name']
            message = contact_form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = contact_form.cleaned_data['sender']
            phone = contact_form.cleaned_data['phone']
            cc_myself = contact_form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

             recipients = ['xxxxx@gmail.com']
             if cc_myself:
             recipients.append(sender)

             send_mail(name, message, sender, recipients)
             contact_form.save()
             print('Successful')
             return redirect('contact')
        else:
            print('Fails')

    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

    context = {
        "contact_form": contact_form,
    }
    template = 'contact.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
    sender = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cc_myself = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Message for {}'.format(self.sender)
```

contact.html:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{contact_form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: What is it that you did differently from the OP?

Comment: I have just tried this code with my own gmail account and it is working....

Comment: EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my gmail account' ,EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password',recipients = ['receiver email address',]

Comment: ContactForm has no attribute save.

Comment: Please download my project and run it into your server. I use python 3 and django 1.11 tls version.

Comment: It prints success but the message doesn’t get sent

Comment: Please see the link .I have taken screen shots of my every steps.   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/edbr9he4lvllshf/AAC9rChRLOT5d87mrV8OF2mAa?dl=0

Comment: I have updated my question to update my terminal output

Comment: what django version are you using?

Comment: found the problem. I realized that I had `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` in my settings file. removing it fixed the problem

Comment: I am using django 1.11 lts version

Comment: @King that could not have been the problem.

Comment: Yes it isn’t. The EMAIL_BACKEND was the problem

Comment: I just tried it. It failed because google gmail requires an app password set up with two factor authentication. Once I used the new generated app password, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're missing your `EMAIL_BACKEND`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 1):

From your output,it clearly shows that the email is being logged to the console which means the sending process is being simulated on your console. This technically constitute sending the email.

Anyway, I suspect this is happening because you have your email backend set to

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

What you need to do is change the email backend to :

> EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

Answer (score -1):

[Django Setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_BACKEND) is the trick!

Django sends the emails in background job, and you have to set this ENV VARs correctly if you want to use and external job manager.