# Can not connect to smtp.gmail.com in Django

Tags: python, php, django, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send email using smtp.gmail.com in Django project.
This is my email settings.

settings.py

```
# Email Settings

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myaccount@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mygooglepassword'
```

views.py

```
...
send_mail( "message title", 
           "message content", 
           "myaccount@gmail.com", 
           ["myaccount@hotmail.com"], 
           fail_silently=False)
```

Whenever I try to send email, I get this error

#### gaierror at /contact-us/

[Errno-2] Name or service not known

I tried the followings.

1. I set my google account's less secure app access on.
2. I unchecked avast antivirus setting 'Setting->Protection->Core Shields->Mail Shield->Scan outbound emails(SMTP)'
3. Tried different ports in email settings. 587 and 25
4. Switched the ssl and tls in email settings.

But it's not sending yet. When I use 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' instead of 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend', it prints email on console.

I double checked my gmail username and password on settings.
Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do some configuration on Google side.

[Reference answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31333304/11607969):

Go to your Google Account settings, find Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps, enable this option.

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I believe your answer is another one step to success. But unfortunately, it gets the same error yet.

Comment: Is your email port opening and not blocked by any firewalls?

Comment: What a pity, I know it is a connection issue but I am not sure where is it if you have configured your Google account for insecure app. 
If I were you, I would create a new temp localhost Django project(not with ssl and any additional stuff) just with the email settings and test send_email functionality with existing settings.

Comment: The less secure app option is now disable by Google as of May 30, 2022...